# Display text in Android

Tags: java, android, text

I know that System.out.println() does not work on Android.
So I need another way to print out some text.

Please help me.

I'm using the Root Tools library

```
class superuser  {
     public static Command c ;{
         if (RootTools.isRootAvailable()) {
             System.out.print("Root found!!");
         }
         else{ System.out.print(("NO ROOT!"));


         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried using logger? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: @svarog it giving me error when i replace it with system.out.println error : cannot resolve sysmbol

Comment: `System.out.println()` does work in android. Check output in `logcat`

Comment: Who told you that it doesn't work? I use it every day.

Comment: then you can't filter it using TAG's

Comment: aren't there any alternative ?

Comment: Using logcat is the usual way in Android  developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Outputing text in android

There are many ways, but usually for testing and debugging processes we use log. The log is not visible to user but you can see it in DDMS.
From what i understand you want to create a dialog or display a textview to users so they know if root is available or not.

---

**1.Logging(for testing and debugging processes)**

we defined TAG in below code because it would be easy to make changes later and our code is more organised

```
private static final String TAG = MyActivity.class.getName();
Log.v(TAG , "here is the line i want to output in logcat");
```

here v in log.v stands for verbose.You may use i for info, e for error etc.

**2.Displaying text to user via a TextView**

First lets import the textview. Let the id of the textview you imported may be "resultTextView"

```
TextView resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
```

now applying your logic and setting its text...

```
     if (RootTools.isRootAvailable()) {
         resultText.setText("Root found!!");
     }
     else{ resultText.setText(("NO ROOT!"));


     }
```

**3.Creating a dialog**

Dialogs are the pop out messages we get.
I would recommend creating a function that takes String message and a String Title as a parameter and creates a dialog using dialog.builder something like this rather than a dialog fragment(which is available in the below link) - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

```
public void alertDialog(String message,String title){

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", null) //we write null cause we don't want 
//to perform any action after ok is clicked, we just want the message to disappear 


            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

Now you can call the method with title and text you want :)

Comment: do i have to add text view to xml?

Comment: @user4847410 yes you have to.They are just like non-editable text boxes,  if you are using android studio or a similar IDE, it is as easy as drag and drop.

Comment: Should I execute all the code in that start onCreate bundle ??

Comment: the first line ie . where we define new object resultTextView should be declared just after beginning onCreate bundle rest of tue code ie. the if else block should be written according to when you want to execute it.

Comment: I'm doing if else in the same block it is ok?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(condition){
 Log.d("message","The root found");
 }
else{
Log.d("message","The root not found");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using logcat ? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

use it like so: `Log.v("myAwesomeApp", "my developer comment");`

then use the log panel in your IDE to read it

Answer (score 0):

Using logcat is the usual way in Android, and the simplest.

```
Log.d("message_id","message content");
```

If you want another way to display log, you can try

https://github.com/orhanobut/logger